# Make django not to process commented out html

Tags: django

I am developing a website using django. I added a link to an element but yet to create view for it.

But django doesn't let me test my changes until I finish writing the view. 
It issues `NoReverseMatch` error. I tried commenting out that part of  html using these `<!-- xxxx -->` but still django issues the same error.

How can I comment out the html so djano won't process it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surround the parts of the template with the [template comment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#comments), and django will ignore it:

```
{# <a href="{% url('does-not-exist') %}">foo</a> #}
```

In most text editors that are aware of django templates, you can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to comment out the templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{# ... #}` or `{% comment 'Blah-blah-blah' %}...{% endcomment %}` [tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#comment).  Also,  you can create `dummy` view and use it in urls instead of not yet created views:

*views.py*

```
def dummy(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse('Dummy View')
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^index/$', views.dummy, name='index'),
    url(r'^page/(\d+)/$', views.dummy, name='page'),
    ...
]
```